# Chromium hardware acceleration and animations makes all monitors lag in video playback

Tags: windows, google-chrome, multiple-monitors, chromium, video-streaming

I have been experiencing some very, very odd issues with Chromium on Windows 10 and 11. I tried two different Chromium based browsers (Chrome and Brave), and they both do the same.

A little about my setup: 1x 4K monitor, 1x 1440p monitor, 1x 1080p monitor, Ryzen 3900X, RTX 3070, and 32GB of RAM. All monitors are set to 100% DPI in Windows and they run at native resolution with latest Nvidia drivers as well.

When a browser is maximized on my 1080p monitor and an animation is playing, such as Facebook's "someone is typing a comment" or just regular CSS animations, video playback on the 4K and 1440p monitors start to lag completely, resulting in the videos going stuck at some point (infinite buffering). The very second I switch tabs or the animations on the 1080p monitor stops, the video starts playing again.

I originally had this problem in Windows 10, but I decided to completely wipe my SSD and install Windows 11. I installed Brave and decided not to import any settings from Chrome, so it was a perfect default installation. However, the exact same problem happens.

If I turn off hardware acceleration in chrome://flags and restart the browsers, it works flawlessly. Video playback is fine, although 4K 60 FPS on YouTube is a bit choppy at times. If I don't maximize the browser and it just runs in a window, it works flawlessly as well.

At this point I'm suspecting a couple of things could be wrong:

- Chromium (unlikely as nobody else has reported this problem afaik)
- Hardware (CPU, GPU, motherboard)

I can eliminate bad drivers because I reinstalled Windows, as well as tried a couple of different Nvidia drivers. I think actual hardware is unlikely, as I only experience issues using Chromium.

Here's a list of things I have tried:

- Different HDMI cable
- Different port on the GPU
- Swap the monitor with another 1080p monitor
- Reinstall Windows
- Change resolutions, refresh rate, etc. of all monitors

To replicate the problem, I simply have to open this page (a square spinning using CSS animations) on my 1080p monitor and play any YouTube video on another monitor: https://codepen.io/teerapuch/pen/vLJXeR

To see a recorded example using my phone (just to rule out any PC issues), here's a link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ufsDsV6_HCg

When the animation is playing, the video playback stops. When I switch to this post's tab (where there are no animations), it resumes the video playback.

Where do I even begin to debug this behavior? There are no errors in the Event Viewer or anywhere else I've looked.

Comment: Have you tried with Firefox? Also have you checked for DPC latency issues? There are a few free tools available for this

Comment: @JamesP I have not tested with Firefox, no. I can try that. Regarding DPC latency - which tool would you prefer I test with? And how would I test it? Start the test and let it complete, then start the test, make the video lag, and then let it complete, then compare results? Never heard of DPC latency before.

Comment: I’ve heard good things about LatencyMon although not used it personally. I would just start the test then try to trigger the situation you mentioned to see if there is a spike in one of the drivers

Comment: @JamesP Well I see no spikes when I introduce the animation, but when looking at the stats after ~1 minute of capture, I do see that the nvlddmkm.sys (Nvidia driver) has the highest DPC count, highest execution, and highest total execution. Other than that, nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: I think your best bet is to try FireFox since it has a completely different architecture. If it has similar problems then it could be something specific to your machine, otherwise it may just be some bug/limitation with Chromium-based browsers

Comment: @JamesP Oh yeah I forgot to mention Firefox - looks like it works flawlessly. So it's definitely something with the Chromium engine. Not sure what it is, though. However, I'm not interested in switching to Firefox as a daily driver. If I don't get more replies here, any clue where else I could ask? I'm ready to offer a 20 dollar bounty to anyone who can fix it.

Comment: Are you using G-sync? I think I read somewhere that it could cause weird issues like this, so if you are using it then it could be worth experimenting with the settings

Comment: @JamesP Hmm G-Sync is actually missing from Nvidia Control Panel. Weird. I'll investigate that problem. But no, pretty sure it's disabled and always has been

Comment: @JamesP Ah, it was disabled on the monitor. Now it shows up and it is indeed disabled. I'll try to enable.. just in case. EDIT: Nope, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out this entire issue was a monitor issue. I still do not know why, and I cannot explain why, but it has now been fixed.

I ditched my old 1080p monitor and bought a brand new 2560x1440 monitor to replace it. Now everything runs smoothly.

If anyone happens to run into this issue, I made myself an userscript (TamperMonkey) that basically disables all CSS animations in the browser. Every 1 second it checks if there are any new animations and then just kills them. Some pages look funky, but that's a good trade-off compared to the lag I experienced.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Disable all animations
// @version      1.0
// @author       mortenmoulder
// @include      *
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// @grant        GM_addElement
// ==/UserScript==

//remove animations globally
GM_addStyle("* { animation-duration: 0s !important; animation-play-state: paused; }");

var ignoreElements = [];

//remove animations inside shadow DOM elements
function findShadowRoots(elements) {
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if(elements[i].shadowRoot) {

            if(ignoreElements.includes(elements[i].shadowRoot) == false) {
                GM_addElement(elements[i].shadowRoot, 'style', { textContent: '* { animation-duration: 0s !important; animation-play-state: paused;' });
                ignoreElements.push(elements[i].shadowRoot);
            }

            findShadowRoots(elements[i].shadowRoot.querySelectorAll("*"));
        }
    }
}

//remove animations every 1 second
setInterval(() => {
    var allNodes = document.querySelectorAll('*');
    findShadowRoots(allNodes);
}, 1000);
```